# SVG shows clipped edge

Tags: html, css, svg

What can I do either using the native SVG syntax or in CSS to fix this clipped edge from appearing in my SVG?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#profile-pic {
  width: 33%;
}
#profile-pic text {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #000;
  -webkit-animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
          animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
@keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="profile-pic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <title>Brandon McConnell</title>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="imageClipPath"><circle cx="250" cy="250" r="116" fill="#FFFFFF" /></clipPath>
</defs>
    <text dy="70" textLength="500">Lorem Ipsum</text>
    <image
    href="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6e25e38e140dda7ac64f7865b3df77ab?s=500"
    clip-path="url(#imageClipPath)"
    width="240"
    height="240"
         x="130"
         y="130"
  />
</svg>
```

I am seeing this in the latest version of Chrome. Screenshot:

[image: example of clipped image edge]

##### System Specs

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
macOS Big Sure - Version 11.6.1 (20G224)
Google Chrome - Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

Comment: On my WIndows10 laptop I am not seeing that border on Chrome/Edge or Firefox. Do you see it at different zoom levels?

Comment: Yes, I tested and see it when zoomed at 50%, 100%, and 150% (and others)

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @AHaworth updated my question to include my system specs. Thank you.

Comment: why are you using SVG here?

Comment: Thanks. Now with the bouncing up and down Lorem Ipsum I am seeing those lines (WIndows10 Chrome/Edge).

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known Chrome bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171601

In the meantime, one work around is to use a mask instead.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#profile-pic {
  width: 33%;
}
#profile-pic text {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #000;
  -webkit-animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
          animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
@keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="profile-pic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <title>Brandon McConnell</title>
<defs>
  <mask id="imageClipPath"><circle cx="250" cy="250" r="116" fill="white" /></mask>
</defs>
    <text dy="70" textLength="500">Lorem Ipsum</text>
    <image
    href="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6e25e38e140dda7ac64f7865b3df77ab?s=500"
    mask="url(#imageClipPath)"
    width="240"
    height="240"
         x="130"
         y="130"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks, Paul! 

Answer (score 1):

The image has a size of 240px. The radius of the clip path is 116. Increasing it to slightly more than half of the image size removes the edge. Changing the `r=116` to `r=120.05` removes the border.

Comment: I've found other sizes like `120.05` that make the border near invisible but at different zoom points, the edges are still visible. In your case, `120.05` appears to hide the edge at all zooms, so that's great! I am not as much looking for a way to hide the borders as I am an explanation as to why they are bleeding outside the clipPath and if there is a "correct" way to avoid the issue.

Comment: This is a very good find, and likely the solution I'll fall back to if a more proper one is not available. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do see the artifact you mention. I found that removing this:

```
#profile-pic, #profile-pic * {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

gets rid of that.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-pic {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="profile-pic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="imageClipPath"><circle cx="250" cy="250" r="116" fill="#FFFFFF" /></clipPath>
  </defs>
    <image
    href="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6e25e38e140dda7ac64f7865b3df77ab?s=500"
    clip-path="url(#imageClipPath)"
    width="240"
    height="240"
    x="130"
    y="130"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: I can still see the clipped edge in your example, same as mine. This clipped edge appears without any use of `backface-visibility`, so I'll remove that from my question.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell - Check that again please. I just edited.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the edit, but as I mentioned, this still appears for me without any use of `backface-visibility`. I believe it may have more to do with my use of `transform` and the `animation` keyframes. Please check my updated question.